# How to temporarily store arrays and objects of data in a View in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, object, swiftui, swift5

Imagine there is cooking app that the user can create their own recipes. The app is integrated with Firebase and gets the core data from Firebase.
In a view, I let the user to create the recipe. So user will input name, ingredients with their sizes and equipment. Somehow I need to store this data to use it within the View and then save it on Firebase once the user press the save button.
How can I store this data temporarily?
The data will be something like the below example. A mixture of arrays and objects.

```
{
  "User": 124213,
  "RecipeName": "Some Name",
  "createdDate": "Some Date",
  "Ingredients": [
    {
      "ingredient": 123,
      "size": 3
    },
    {
      "ingredient": 234,
      "size": 3
    },
    {
      "ingredient": 294,
      "size": 2
    },
    {
      "ingredient": 736,
      "size": 2
    },
    {
      "ingredient": 150,
      "size": 4
    }
  ],
  "Equipment": [
    [ 123, 234 ],
    [ 294, 736 ]
  ]
}
```

I dont know how developer deal with such situation where they need to keep data temporarily on IOS before sending it to Firebase.

Any idea or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your data structure using structs or classes depending on your needs and conform them to codable:

```
struct Recipe: Codable {
let user: Int
let recipeName, createdDate: String
let ingredients: [Ingredient]
let equipment: [[Int]]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case user = "User"
    case recipeName = "RecipeName"
    case createdDate
    case ingredients = "Ingredients"
    case equipment = "Equipment"
 }
}

   // MARK: - Ingredient
   struct Ingredient: Codable {
   let ingredient, size: Int
   }
```

Once you need to post your data to Firebase convert it to JSON and post it.

```
let dataRecipe = try? JSONEncoder().encode(myRecipeObject)
```

Comment: Thanks very helpful. I posted a question regarding updating values in this struct [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977451/how-to-update-the-values-of-a-struct-in-a-view). It would be great if you answer that.